# problem with jdk 6 and tomcat 7

Tags: jdk, tomcat

I installed tomcat 7 and am using JDK 6

when I start tomcat7 I get this

```
sudo service tomcat7 start 
* Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomcat7
start-stop-daemon: unable to start /usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-6-jdk/bin/java (No such file or directory)
                                                                     [ OK ]
```

java and javac have symlinks in `usr/bin`.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the path of the java file in the tomcat7 file, now the tomcat7 starts fine, but
when I try wget

```
wget localhost:8080
--2013-01-07 16:47:44--  http://localhost:8080/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2013-01-07 16:47:44 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```